# How to Reset Password in Parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, password-recovery

So when the user wants to recover their password they tap a button and a subview appears with a`UITextField` and a `UIButton`. After the user enters their e-mail I want the `UIButton` to send the email. I am missing the referral to the `UITextField` Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)recoverPassword:(id)sender {

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(12, 51, 298, 497);

UIView *infoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
infoView.opaque = NO;
infoView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8f];
infoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
infoView.tag = 01;

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 200, 280, 30)];
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIButton *getPassword = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 265, 280, 36)];
getPassword.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[getPassword addTarget:self
                action:@selector(getUserPassword:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[infoView addSubview:textField];
[infoView addSubview:getPassword];
[self.view addSubview:infoView];

 }

- (void)getUserPassword:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sendPassword {

[PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:**Missing Part**];
[[self.view viewWithTag:01] removeFromSuperview];
NSLog(@"Dissmissed Info SubView");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating subviews (UITextField, UIButton, etc) only on the local scope (inside the method scope), thus they won't be accessible to other methods of the same class.
Try creating an ivar for the class you have these methods in, and assigning the values to the ivar, so the same variables will be accessible in your `-getUserPassword:` method.

P.S. Same approach, but applied to `infoView`, would eliminate the need to access it via `viewWithTag`, because you will be able to access it directly.